# Get IP of producers sending messages to queue/exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

For troubleshooting purpose I want to get list of producers sending messages to a particular queue or exchange. I dont see any option in rabbitmq console to get the above details. Some producers are piling up a paricular queue, I am trying to figure out the IP of producer piling up messages in the queue.

Can any one please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have this information by default, but you can use the message headers to do that.

for example:

```
string message = "Hello World!";
var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

var properties = new BasicProperties();
properties.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
properties.Headers.Add("senderip", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
properties.Headers.Add("custominfo", "info" );

channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "mykey", basicProperties: properties,body: body);
```

When you recevice the message you can decode the headers